# How to delay code being executed in C#

Tags: c#

I am coding a simple licence system script for my C# console program, and I am trying to delay the code being ran.

```
Task ShutdownTask = new Task(SilverEnvironment.PerformShutDown);
                            ShutdownTask.Start();
                            SilverEnvironment.GetGame().GetModerationTool().LogStaffEntry("SERVER", string.Empty, "Shutdown", "Invalid licence provided.");
```

That is the code that I want excecuted in a timed matter, instead of being ran right away. I am not too good with C#, but I know the basics.

Comment: putting this on a thread and then sleeping the thread should do the job, have a look here for more information on threads: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Vstudio/System.Threading.Thread(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Task.Delay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you do not want to worry about creating a timer on your own. See this for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873.aspx

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21177.visual-c-thread-sleep-vs-task-delay.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to generate an event after a certain period. Don't forget to disable the timer, otherwise it will repeat the event after the same interval.

Answer (score 0):

```
new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback((obj) => {
    // your code
}, null, 1000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
```

where `1000` is the time delay.

This code starts `Timer` with initial delay, when time elapses `TimerCallback` will be called asynchronously. Period `Infinite` means that callback will be called only once.
This will not stop executing current thread, so if you want to stop current thread then better use `Threat.Sleep`:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
// your code
```

Comment: please add some explantation to your answer, showing how your proposed code will solve the proble, and why the what the questioner was missing

Answer (score 0):

Add the following before executing code. 1000 for each second to wait.

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of following methods:

1) Thread.Sleep(5000);
         OR
2) await Task.Delay(5000);